# File Upload into MySQL DB + ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I have a question about uploading files into an SQL Database with ASP.NET MVC.
This is my table where I want to store the image:

> **Table "deliverables"**
>   - item_id
>   - deliverable_image

item_id is from another table where I store the name, description, tags, ... of the image!

This is my Create View of the DeliverableController:

> @model GDMfrontEnd.Models.DeliverableViewModel
>
> ```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Create";
> }
>
> <h2>Create</h2>
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
>
>     <fieldset>
>         <legend>EventViewModel</legend>
>
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             <!--
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
>             -->
>             <form action="/profile/upload"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>               <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
>               <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
>
>               <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
>             </form>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image)
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
>         </div>
>
>         <p>
>             <input type="submit" value="Create" />
>         </p>
>     </fieldset>
> }
>
> <div>
>     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
> </div>
>
> @section Scripts {
>     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
>
>     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
>     @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
>     </script>
> }
> ```

My DeliverableViewModel looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GDMfrontEnd.Models
{
    public class DeliverableViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Thumbnail")]
        public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "VideoUrl")]
        public string VideoUrl { get; set; }

        public long UsernameID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my connectionstring:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="gdmwebsiteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=root;database=gdmwebsite&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But how can I upload files instead of just text?
I've done some tutorials but none of them are very clear and none of them work with MySQL Database.

Niels

Comment: I've added my connectionstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
model.Image.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
byte[] data = target.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want, regardless that I don't like to save byte arrays in the DB

First change the add the following parameters in your form this allows you send the images

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null ,new { @enctype= "multipart/form-data"}))
```

Modified your change the  two properties mapped in your model from byte array to type `HttpPostedFileBase`

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase Thumbnail  { get; set; }
```

Add the properties in your view like

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Thumbnail, new {type="file"})
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Image , new {type="file"})
```

Remove the internal form you shouldn't have two nested forms,

Now when you receive the values you can save using SaveAs Method or convert into byte array

```
model.Image.SaveAs();
```

For more information [here's the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx)